# android layout with fragment breaks when toolbar is there

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Couldn't find a more appropriate title but my problem is the following. I have a `LinearLayout` that contains another `LinearLayout` and a fragment. I also want to add the `toolbar` but when I do so, then I only see the `toolbar` and the other screen is just white.

Here is the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/categories_layout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <ExpandableListView
                android:id="@+id/categories_listView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mainPane"
            android:name="xeniasis.mymarket.Products"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:theme="@style/ToolbarTheme" />
```

And the `fragment` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="xeniasis.mymarket.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/productsGridview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:numColumns="3"></GridView>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|start"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This only happens when I have a `fragment`, cause I previously had the same xml with a static layout where the `fragment` is now.

Comment: "other screen is just white" - What is the Fragment supposed to display?

Comment: @cricket_007 on first load the `activity_main` layout. I haven't gone any further. It is suppose to change layout depending on user interaction

Comment: Well, `android:orientation="horizontal"` seems like a poor way to show a Toolbar

Comment: doesn't do any difference if I add it in the inside `LinearLayout`

Comment: Your main layout is a horizontal Linear Layout and the first child is the Toolbar, which has width "match_parent", that forces everything else off the right hand side of the screen.

Comment: What I was trying to say was that the activity's layout should have `android:orientation="vertical"`, because you want a toolbar on top of and over the fragment and listview.

Comment: @LewisMcGeary ohhh man, you are right! The parent `LinearLayout` needs `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: would you like to write an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you used a LinearLayout with

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

and since the toolbar has `match_parent` as width it occupies all the screen.
Try to use

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in the root layout